# Find Object with Minimum Value of a Key in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a List in TypeScript declared as `myList: Package[]`. The model declaration of `Package` is shown below -

```
export class Package {
ID: Number;
Price: Number;
```

}

I want to get a `Package` object with minimum **`Price`** value something like

```
myList.min(p=>p.Price)
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yu can use the `reduce` function:

```
myList.reduce((r, e) => r.Price < e.Price ? r : e);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if its the best way, but we can use lodash minBy to do this as below:

```
_.minBy(myList, 'Price');
```

You can take a look at the documentation of lodash here [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#minBy)

Answer (score 1):

Array `sort` is intuitive:

```
[...arr].sort((a, b) => b.p - a.p)[0]
```

It also allows to find objects with both minimum and maximum values when necessary.

While `reduce` is preferable and more efficient way to do this (as another answer explains).